Retirement of JDK Locale Format (Canada ICU applied)
In an email sent by Salesforce I saw:
Does Salesforce enable ICU locale formats for English (Canada) locale 'Yes'
Currently with a SOQL query I have this:

Will the ICU that will be applied be that of France?

Could you confirm that the ICU applied is not English (Canada) (but France ICU) or that I will be able to apply the French ICU?
